# When run tests on Heroku I get Could not download source code tarball error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ember.js

when I want to run my tests **Heroku** throws an error and no shown output.

```
could not download source code tarball
```

I tried to run again but every time i try **run again** or **run again without cache** option, i got same error.

I searched this error but couldn't get any information.

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is, Heroku couldn't get code that is needed for the test because Heroku doesn't have access to your repository. You have to check your auth access for the git provider(Github, Gitlab etc.). I deleted the auth. permission on github after that I'd gave permission to Github on Heroku. After that, all things work perfectly.